# Why are Frames and JFrames set to invisible by default?

Tags: java, swing

Does anyone know the rational for Java Frames and JFrames being set to invisible by default?

i.e. you have to call myFrameObject.setVisible(true) or you end up with an invisible application interface.

This has been bugging me since you don’t see this in other languages like C# or Objective-C. I was wondering if it was intended to be a time-saver or if the Java architects were just having a bad day.

Knowing this will help me understand the ultimate answer to life, the universe, and everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I always assumed it was so you could populate the window before displaying it. Otherwise you could see a bunch of controls shuffle around as they were added. Probably not a noticeable problem with todays machines + JITs, but in the early days of Java with slower machines and bytecode interpreters in the JVMs it might have made a difference.

It also mimics the way top-level windows work in X11: you create the window, and then later you "map" it (make it visible).

Comment: It doesn't take time to place components over the container

Comment: @org.life.java everything takes some amount of time. Anyway, see my update to the answer. Note that Java was created in the early 90's and the early JVMs interpreted bytecode.

Comment: Ok, But Still I am not much sure that this is the only reason.

Comment: +1 This what I've always assumed too. I've dealt with this using Flex 3. It can be difficult to know when the control is placed and sized. It can be even harder to know when the control is actually READY to use. The whole `setVisible` thing is a nuisance, true. Effective or not, I've always assumed this was to help curb that problem a little.

Comment: @org.life.java I mentioned two possible reasons. Solaris + X11 (and Motif, I believe) was the "native platform" of Java in the early days, so it seems very likely that certain aspects of AWT were inherited from X11. Swing then inherited these aspects from AWT.

Comment: @org.life.java - OK ... so what are the *other* reasons?

Comment: Thanks all. I imagine in the early days of Java with slower computers it could take a noticeable amount of time to populate a window with a lot of components. IMO it would be a better user experience waiting a few seconds then displaying a completed and ready to use UI vs. making them watch a UI being constructed.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, Swing components are not real components from the OS point of view. Every Swing component needs to be "realized". This is done by invoking the pack() or setVisible() methods. Only at this time will the Swing component be mapped to a peer component of the OS.

And remember when you add components to a visible GUI the components will not appear anyway because you need to invoke the layout manager to layout all the components. So even if the frame was visible automatically, in this case you would still need to invoke frame.validate() to make sure the components are layed out properly.

I think it is a better design to add all the components and then make it visibile once you have finished adding everything to the frame. This way you only layout the components once, not after every component is added. Maybe with other languages that use absolute sizes and positioning this is not a big deal because they don't have the concept of layout managers.